# How to append a struct in a goroutine

Tags: go

I have a goroutine with a switch which want to append an interface to a struct but when a run it I don't receive an error but it not append any response
How do you write that in Go to make it concurrency-safe?

This is my code:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

for _, v := range inputParameters.Entities {
    go func(v domain.Entity) {
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done()

        var f func(
            v domain.Entity,
            result *domain.Resoponse,
        )(interface{}, Error) // Signature of all Get methods

        switch v.Name {
        case "process1":
            f = 1Processor{}.Get
        case "process2":
            f = 2Processor{}.Get
        case "process3":
            f = 3Processor{}.Get
        default:
            return
        }
        res, err := f(v, result)

        if err != nil {
            mapError.Error = append(mapError.Error, err)
        } else {
            result.Mu.Lock()
            defer result.Mu.Unlock()
            result.Entities = append(result.Entities, res)
        }
    }(v)
}

wg.Wait()
return result, mapError
```

For reference, here is the `Response` type:

```
type Resoponse struct {
    Mu      sync.Mutex
    Entities []interface{}
}
```

Comment: It looks like there's a data race on `mapError.Error`.  Protect it with a mutex as you down with `result.Entities`.  Run the application with the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) and fix any reported problems.

Comment: Do `wg.Add(1)` just before the goroutine. There's no guarantee that any of the logic within the goroutines gets done before you reach `wg.Wait()` so don't put the `wg.Add(1)`s in the goroutines.

Comment: Also stylistically I'd recommend omitting the argument names in declaration of `var f`. Since you're just declaring `f` and defining its signature, not actually defining what `f` does it with its input arguments, it's confusing to have the names of the arguments there especially since they are the same as other variables you're actually using in that logic. So consider just having `var f func(domain.Entity, *domain.Resoponse)(interface{}, Error)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `wg.Add(1)` just before the goroutine. There's no guarantee that any of the logic within the goroutines gets done before you reach `wg.Wait()` so don't put the `wg.Add(1)`s in the goroutines.